# Problema de enlaces permanentes de wordpress instalado subcarpeta en laravel

Tags: laravel, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

tengo un entorno de laravel el cual tengo los siguientes aplicativos en las siguientes rutas:

1. dominio.com
2. dominio.com/sub/app-1
3. dominio.com/sub/app-2

Ahora, he instalado wordpress en la ruta `dominio.com/sub/` y he puesto en él que haya enlaces permanentes de wordpress (ejemplo: dominio.com/sub/posts/post-1), pero al ponerlos `dominio.com/sub/app-1` deja de funciona y da un **404 de wordpress**. Pero si quito los enlaces permanentes vuelve a funcionar `dominio.com/sub/app-1`.

He investigado bastante que es por la configuración de .htaccesss de wordpress que hay que ignorar la carpeta `sub/app-x` he usado `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(app-1|app-2) [NC]` en el .htaccesss de wordpress, logró ignorarlo pero ahora sale **404 de apache** y no aparece la app de laravel. Muchas gracias si alguien puede ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de indagar tanto, encontré mi respuesta, aclaro, primer lugar, que el directorio raíz de la app es el blog de wordpress:

1. **dominio.com/sub** (wordpress, instalado en laravel/public/sub)
2. **dominio.com/sub/app-x** (app laravel controlado por la ruta: laravel/routes/web.php)

En mi caso **no** hay que hacer nada en el **.htaccesss de laravel/public** todo el problema se encuentra en el **.htaccess de wordpress** (laravel/public/sub)

La idea es ignorar la ruta de la app de laravel con `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/app-x` y luego crear un nuevo módulo a puntando `/sub/app-x` al `index.php` de **laravel/public**, el problema de editar el **.htaccess** de wordpress es que él sobrescribe este archivo cuando hacemos cambios "Xs" en WordPress, para eso tenemos que usar un hack para evitar que Wordpress no edite el .htaccesss como explica [acá](https://ayudawp.com/evitar-wordpress-cambie-htaccess/).

El código final, en .htaccesss de wordpress, que me funcionó es este:

```
# INICIO Codigo ignorado por apache
<IfModule mod_ignore_wordpress.c>
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
# FIN  Codigo ignorado por apache

#NUESTO CODIGO QUE NO EDITA WORDPRESS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/app-x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#Nuevo Modulo
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/app-x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```